# "As for" meaning in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning, spoken-english

An extract from an article:

> For global climate change, **as for hunger,** the countries that experience the worst problems have the fewest resources to address them.

What does **as for** mean here?

Dictionaries say it means: **with regard to.**

(By the way that is the first sentence of a new topic.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context it means *also for*.

The sentence is making a statement that applies to two different metrics - *Global Climate Change* and *hunger* - that the countries that experience the worst problems have the fewest resources to address them.

So:

- The countries that experience the worst *climate change* problems have the fewest resources to address them.

AND

- The countries that experience the worst *hunger* problems have the fewest resources to address them.